# WordPress Message WordPress 6.0 is available! Please inform the administrator

Tags: wordpress

I'm getting after logging in to my WordPress 5.4 site with my admin account, the message "WordPress 6.0 is available! Please inform the administrator."

Further I'm not able to update/administrate plugins. The site is not part of a WordPress Network.

(Also sometimes I received some issues when saving changes in the related Elementor areas).

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

Login to your Hosters FTP location, go to the folder wordpress and open wp-config.php.

In the config file I changed the last line from 'true' to 'false':

Was:

```
"define('disallow_file_mods' true)"
```

After the change (= solution):

```
"define('disallow_file_mods' true)"
```

Afterwards logout and login again.